# Trait object causing type mismatch

Tags: rust

While implementing a trait from an external library, I found my initial implementation unable to compile.

```rust
// From library
trait SomeTrait {
    fn do_thing(&self) -> Result<i32, Box<dyn Error + Sync + Send + 'static>>;
}

// My code
struct Foo;

impl SomeTrait for Foo {
    fn do_thing(&self) -> Result<i32, Box<dyn Error + Sync + Send + 'static>> {
        i32::from_str("42").map_err(|e| Box::new(MyError))
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyError;
impl Display for MyError {...}
impl Error for MyError {}
```

Error from rustc v1.55.0:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:17:9
   |
16 |     fn do_thing(&self) -> Result<i32, Box<dyn Error + Sync + Send + 'static>> {
   |                           --------------------------------------------------- expected `Result<i32, Box<(dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static)>>` because of return type
17 |         i32::from_str("42").map_err(|e| Box::new(MyError))
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait object `dyn std::error::Error`, found struct `MyError`
   |
   = note: expected enum `Result<_, Box<(dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static)>>`
              found enum `Result<_, Box<MyError>>`
```

If I change the body of `do_thing` to be this, the compiler is happy.

```rust
match i32::from_str("42") {
    Ok(v) => Ok(v),
    Err(_) => Err(Box::new(MyError)),
}
```

I can also do this which the compiler also accepts but is incredibly ugly.

```rust
i32::from_str("42").map_err(|e| Box::new(MyError) as Box<dyn Error + Sync + Send + 'static>)
```

I obviously have a working solution but I'd like to know what the differences between the implementations are to avoid pulling my hair out in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transformation from `Box<MyError>` to `Box<dyn Error + ...>` is known as an *unsizing coercion* (because it converts from a type with statically known size to one without). The exact rules for which types can be so converted are defined by the special traits [`CoerceUnsized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.CoerceUnsized.html) and [`Unsize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/marker/trait.Unsize.html). (These traits are currently unstable, but that just means you are not allowed to implement or directly call them in stable Rust; you can still make use of their effects.)

The documentation tells us the following implementation exists:

```rust
impl<T, U, A> CoerceUnsized<Box<U, A>> for Box<T, A>
where
    T: Unsize<U> + ?Sized,
    A: Allocator,
    U: ?Sized,
```

This generic implementation covers the case of

```rust
impl CoerceUnsized<Box<dyn Error + ...>> for Box<MyError>
```

so that you can coerce inside `map_err`, but there is no such implementation for `Result`, so you cannot perform the coercion on an entire `Result`, and must arrange for it to happen (implicitly or explicitly) on the error type alone, by bringing the error value out to its own variable of type `Box<MyError>` which is assigned or returned to a destination that requires `Box<dyn Error + ...>`.

---

That's the “why” you asked for. Now a tip for writing the code: you can use `as _` to say "I want a coercion, but please infer the type because it's obvious enough”:

```rust
    i32::from_str("42").map_err(|e| Box::new(MyError) as _)
```

This way you don't have to write the lengthy `dyn` type. You could also define a type alias to reduce repetition while still being explicit:

```rust
type DynError = Box<dyn Error + Sync + Send + 'static>;

...

    i32::from_str("42").map_err(|e| Box::new(MyError) as DynError)
```

However, for the specific case of `Box<dyn Error>`, an even better option is to just use the `?` operator with its automatic `Into` conversion:

```rust
    fn do_thing(&self) -> Result<i32, Box<dyn Error + Sync + Send + 'static>> {
        Ok(i32::from_str("42")?)
    }
```

This works because `?` returns the error with an `Into::into(e)` conversion, and the standard library contains a generic conversion from *any* `Error` to `Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>`:

```rust
impl<'a, E: Error + Send + Sync + 'a> From<E> for Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync + 'a>
```

This is probably what the library expected you to use.

In this simple case, the `?` is also equivalent to:

```rust
    fn do_thing(&self) -> Result<i32, Box<dyn Error + Sync + Send + 'static>> {
        i32::from_str("42").map_err(Into::into)
    }
```

Comment: A small supplement for the first part: We don't specify a return type for the closre passed to `map_err()`, so the compiler needs to infer it. The compiler first looks at the return expression of the closure, and uses the type of that expression as the return type. Sometimes that type is not a complete type, in which case the compiler uses information from the context to infer the remaining bits. So the compiler first infers the type "from the inside out". If the approach were the other way around – first looking at the contex, then at the expression inside, it would actually work.

Comment: Since then, the compiler could infer the complete return type of the closure as `Box<dyn Error + Sync + Send + 'static>` from the return type of the function, and use an unsizing coercion to convert the return expression to that type. But that's not what the compiler does. I don't think this detail is documented anywhere.

Comment: I was unaware of unsizing.  `Ok(i32::from_str("42")?)` is pretty slick.  Thanks!